# Explanation about gretel gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4.0 + ruby 2.0.0 + gretel

config/breadcrumbs.rb:

```
# Root crumb
crumb :root do
  link "Home", root_path
end

# Issue list
crumb :issues do
  link "All issues", issues_path
end

# Issue
crumb :issue do |issue|
  link issue.title, issue
  parent :issues
end
```

please can anyone explain what is :root,Home,root_path ?

**application.html.erb**

```
<%= breadcrumbs pretext: "You are here: ",
                separator: " &rsaquo; " %>
```

**_user_listing.html.erb**

```
<% breadcrumb :users, @users %>
```

But i am getting error "Breadcrumb :users not found."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:root` and `root_path` are default Rails items pointing to the root path `/` of your website. `Home` is the text of that link.

Comment: is :root a controller name ?

Comment: No, it's just a symbol/name/key. Gretel wants you to 'name' your routes, so this one is named `:root`.